# symfony2.5 maxlength deprecated

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to know why was max_length in form type deprecated?

[image]

And how to achieve the desired effect the cleanest way now ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See related [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7148) on Github. This option only add html attribute to textarea. You can manually add it via attributes:

```
$builder->add('field', 'textarea', array(
    'attr' => array('maxlength' => 255),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it in builder:

```
$builder->add('field', 'textarea', array(
    'attr' => array('maxlength' => 255),
));
```

or in twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.field, {'attr': {'maxlength': 500}}) }}
```

IMPORTANT! Attribute value must be `int`, string will dont work:

```
$builder->add('field', 'textarea', array(
    'attr' => array('maxlength' => '255'),
));
```